# .S assembly code Macro to apply another macro to multiple registers in .S

Tags: assembly, gcc, gnu-assembler

In .S assembly code, I want to write a macro that takes as "argument" another macro, that is then applied to multiple registers. A minimal example would be:

```
.macro add_macro reg1 reg2
    add reg1 reg2
.endm

.macro apply_macro func reg1 reg2
    func reg1
.endm

test_rax:
    apply_macro add_macro %rax, %rdi
```

However, when I want to compile this macro, it does not work:

```
gcc test.S -c -o test.o
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:10: Error: no such instruction: `func reg1'
```

Is there any way to define a macro that applies another macro to certain registers? Note that for the use case at hand, I have to use a macro and cannot use a function.

Comment: Maybe try "/func reg1" to specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I want to compile this macro, it does not work:
> `` test.S:10: Error: no such instruction: `func reg1' ``

That's because the `apply_macro` body doesn't do any parameter substitutions. The following edited variant of your macros work for me:

```
.macro add_macro reg1 reg2
    add \reg1, \reg2
.endm

.macro apply_macro func reg1 reg2
    \func \reg1 \reg2
.endm

test_rax:
    apply_macro add_macro %rax %rdi
```